# Crop PDF Graphics

Tags: tables, pdfpages, pandoc, html, latex2html

I have a number of HTML snippets which I want to programmatically insert a rendering of into different cells of a tabular environment. I've tried a number of tools to convert these into latex such as pandoc and html2latex, however, all of these lose a lot of formatting information that I would like to keep: alignment, colour, etc...

I've also tried to convert the HTML snippets into pdfs and then include these snippets into the tabular environment using `\includepdf` macro from the `pdfpages` package, however, I am unsure how to trim these pdfs to get exactly the area of interest and of course, a full page with rendered HTML on it will not fit into the tabular environment.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could carry out this task programmatically?

Comment: use \includegraphics to include the pdf not \includepdf which includes whole pages

Comment: Thank you, that and the pdfcrop tool did the trick perfectly :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\includegraphics` to include the pdf not `\includepdf` which includes whole pages.

You can crop the pdf in advance using pdfcrop or similar tools or crop the view while including the pdf with `\includegraphics[viewport=10 20 30 40, clip]{file.pdf}` where 10,20 and 30,40 are the lower left and upper right coordinates of the part you want to see.